# Why it is necessary to use internal signal for process?

Tags: vhdl

I'm learning VHDL from the root, and everything is OK except this. I found this from Internet. This is the code for a left shift register.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity lsr_4 is
  port(CLK, RESET, SI : in  std_logic;
       Q              : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
       SO             : out std_logic);
end lsr_4;

architecture sequential of lsr_4 is
  signal shift : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin
  process (RESET, CLK)
  begin
    if (RESET = '1') then
      shift <= "0000";
    elsif (CLK'event and (CLK = '1')) then
      shift <= shift(2 downto 0) & SI;
    end if;
  end process;
  Q  <= shift;
  SO <= shift(3);
end sequential;
```

My problem is the third line from bottom. My question is, why we need to pass the internal signal value to the output?  Or in other words, what would be the problem if I write `Q <= shift (2 downto 0) & SI`?

Comment: Are you asking why you can't remove the `shift` signal and just use `Q` throughout?

Comment: yes..that's my question....

Comment: ... in that case, see pedroni's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the shown code, the `Q` output of the `lsr_4` entity comes from a register (`shift` representing a register stage and being connected to `Q`). If you write the code as you proposed, the `SI` input is connected directly (i.e. combinationally) to the `Q` output. This can also work (assuming you leave the rest of the code in place), it will perform the same operation logically expect eliminate one clock cycle latency. However, it's (generally) considered good design practice to have an entity's output being registered in order to not introduce long "hidden" combinational paths which are not visible when not looking inside an entity. It usually makes designing easier and avoids running into timing problems.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is just a shift register, so no combinational blocks should be inferred (except for input and output buffers, which are I/O related, not related to the circuit proper).

Second, the signal called "shift" can be eliminated altogether by specifying Q as "buffer" instead of "out" (this is needed because Q would appear on both sides of the expression; "buffer" has no side effects on the inferred circuit). A suggestion for your code follows.

Note: After compiling your code, check in the Netlist Viewers / Technology Map Viewer tool what was actually implemented.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity generic_shift_register is
  generic (
    N: integer := 4);
  port(
    CLK, RESET, SI: in std_logic;
    Q: buffer std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
    SO: out std_logic);
end entity;

architecture sequential of generic_shift_register is
begin
  process (RESET, CLK)
  begin
    if (RESET = '1') then
      Q <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
      Q <= Q(N-2 downto 0) & SI;
    end if;
  end process;
  SO <= Q(N-1);
end architecture;
```

Comment: @pedroni..ok..now it's clear to me....I have another question. As far as I know, the statements within the process execute sequentially (one after another)...in my code, if a reset is high between the statement     "shift <= shift(2 downto 0) & SI" and "end process", then what will happen??? thanks in advance...

Comment: It is very important NOT to think of VHDL as a program, but rather as a CODE. Hence you can break your question into two questions: 1) Ask what CIRCUIT will be inferred from the code; 2) Next, ask what this CIRCUIT will do when (whatever you want to ask...) happens. In your case, the circuit inferred from the code is a shift register with an ASYNCHRONOUS reset. Therefore, whenever the reset signal is asserted, the flip-flops are reset, regardless of anything else. I hope this comment helps...

Comment: @user3255764 Be sure to note that the buffer keyword might give you trouble with some vendor tools as the buffer keyword was kind of virulent in VHDL-87 and VHDL-93: buffer ports can only be connected to other buffer ports, leading to your whole design needing buffer ports once you use one of them down in the hierarchy.

The common workaround is indeed to use an intermediate signal or use VHDL-2008, where you're allowed to read outputs (thus saving one signal).